# Site doesn't work correct on Safari

Tags: html, css, safari, opera

I Created this site for a school project, it works perfect on all browsers... except safari (and internet explorer but Yeah.. IE..). Anyway my class="logo1" doesn't fall behind my class="middentextvak1" anymore, while it does perfectly on other browsers. I really don't know what to do anymore.

http://athena.fhict.nl/users/i283951/NRV/home.html

I don't know if it's neccesary to put on the code because it's a lot.

I've uploaded 2 pictures in which you can see the logo is placed correctly in the first one:
http://nl.tinypic.com/view.php?pic=fvv8cp&s=8#.U6c87fl_vcM

and in the second one you can see in the picture the logo falling to the bottom:
(see comment, can't post because of rep)

html:

```
<div class="midden">
    <img class="logo1" src="images/logo.png">
    <div class="middentextvak">
        <h1>Welkom bij autorijschool NRV! </h1>
        <p>In Veldhoven en omgevingen verzorgen wij uw complete rijopleiding in onze volkswagen.
            Een rijopleiding met oog voor detail. U en uw behoefte staan hierbij steeds centraal.
            Onze ervaren instructeur geeft u een moderne rijopleiding geheel afgestemd op uw aanvangsniveau. Zo ben u altijd verzekerd van het zo mogelijk behalen van uw rijbewijs tegen een zo laag mogelijke prijs.
            <br><br>
            Klik <a href="http://www.rijschoolgegevens.nl/index.asp?pageid=2&examenplaats=75&rijschoolid=5285&fromsearch=1">hier</a> voor de meest recente slagingspercentage.
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="contactvlak1">
        <h1>Contactgegevens</h1>
        <p><b>Autorijschool NRV</b>
        <br>Grasplein 2
        <br>06-21710000
        <br>info@autorijschoolNRV.nl
        <br>55.18.77.391 ABN Amro
    </div> 
</div>
```

css:

```
.middentextvak1
{
    position: relative;
    display: block;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    width: 43%;
    height: 90%;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    margin-top: 7%;
    z-index: 10;
}

.logo1
{
    position: fixed;
    display: block;
    margin-left: 17%;
    margin-right: auto;
    width:70%;
    z-index: -1;
    opacity:0.5;
    clear: both;
}
```

Comment: It's annoying when this happens.  Try posting some samples of your code.  Meanwhile, here's a possible solution to your issue: try setting a positive z-index on your `.middentextvalk1` in your CSS.  Usually the default is 0, but Safari might handle it differently.

Comment: Please read the close reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using position:absolute instead of position: fixed on the .logo1 style.  That should position it relative to the midden div.

Also: Safari on Windows is now obsolete, so you only really need to worry about it on a mac.

If you are wanting it to be fixed (ie always in the same position), then this line is preventing that for me in Firefox and Safari -

```
@media only screen and (orientation:landscape){
body {  
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(0deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(0deg);
  transform: rotate(0deg);
 }
}
```

not sure what you are trying to do with that.

It would probably also make more sense to set the logo as a background image if it is working as a background image rather than content.